# how to determine what headers are necessary in form submission

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I am writing a python script to collect a large amount of data, unfortunately this involves submitting a few web forms to get the information that I am interested in.  Since this has to be repeated a few thousand times it makes sense to automate it.

I have never dealt with the forms aspect of this sort of thing so I have a few questions.  Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
url = 'http://example.com/result.do'
values = {'id' : 'value', 'id' : 'value', 'submit' : 'Submit'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

My Questions:
Do I need to pass all the form fields even if I don't select them?

Do I need to pass HTTP headers with this, if so could someone link me to a good explanation of this?

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the [`Mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module. It allows you to select a form, fill fields, select options, and click buttons. It automatically generates the form data that the form would have submitted in a normal browser.

Here's a nice little tutorial/example: http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/